How and where can I find meaningful feedback on my practice research articles?
I graduated with a B.Div in 2020 but unfortunately, I was forced to enter the workforce before I could achieve my dream of working in academia. I want to eventually return at some point to continue my studies and get a master's and PhD. I won't be able to do that any time soon. So, in the meantime, I have been advised to write practice research articles to try and achieve proficiency in research skills and writing. Are there any places online that I can look to get helpful feedback on my practice articles? Bonus if its in the field of Religious Studies.

Maybe check with the person who advised you to do so?
